# How to display a temp file in an iframe?

Tags: java, jsf, jasper-reports

I am working with Java, Jasper Reports, and JSF. I want to generate a report in PDF format and can display it in an `iframe` something like this because on the same page to be able to put filters to reports and so on .. the report is generated correctly as a temp file even when I paste the path in the browser will display correct. but to put that route in an iframe I get the following error:

```
Not allowed to load the local resource: file :/ / / C :/ Users / Juanes ~ 1/AppData/Local/Temp/reportePedidosTemporal1922509630584311367.pdf
```

this is my code:

```
public void prueba(AjaxBehaviorEvent evento)
{
    try
    {   
         Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         parametros.put("autor", "Juan Esteban");
         parametros.put("titulo", "Reporte de Pedidos");

         List<PedidosVO> listaPedidos = new ArrayList<PedidosVO>();

         for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
         { 
              PedidosVO pedido = new PedidosVO(""+i,"Cliente:"+i,(i+1));
              pedido.setPuntos(i);
              listaPedidos.add(pedido); 
         }

        JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Reportes\\Reporte2Pedidos.jrxml");

        JasperReport reporte = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);

        //-**-**-/*-/ 

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametros,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listaPedidos));

        byte[] flujo  = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("reportePedidosTemporal",".pdf");
        System.out.println(tempFile.setReadable(true));
        escribirByte(tempFile,flujo);
        tempFile.deleteOnExit();

        if(tempFile.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("RUTA : "+tempFile.getPath());
            url = tempFile.getPath();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Any ideas, suggestions would be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a *URL* that points to the PDF that you load into the iframe.  As it stands, you're attempting to load a file directly from the filesystem.  This means your site will attempt to load a file from the end user's filesystem directly, which is not allowed for obvious reasons.

Generate the PDF on your server, then generate a URL that points to it.  Then set that as the iframe source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will research how to do this